# jQuery and Modals - Automatic Popup after PHP pass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Strange thing keeping up at night not figuring out what I am doing wrong.

Setup a form that checks through  my algorithim whether user is registered or not in system through PHP and through mySQL. Upon successful registeration - I want the form to dissapear (which works fine) using jQuery and then I want a new modal to popup.

My understanding with things you want to load up is that you intially put it in the HTML of the document but make the visibility to "none" in CSS. When you want to make it visible, you use jQuery to toggle the class to become "visible" and then you can make run your function via jQuery to trigger it.

Everything works fine including the hiding of the section #joinnow (which is where the user registers initially) but I can't seem to get anything to popup afterwards... any idea why?

Note: .popup() is native to jquery Popup Overlay - though I have tried several different plugins and none work...

```js
  $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'test_signup.php',
            data: {'name' : name, 'email' : email},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.btn-light').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('.sign-up').css('opacity', '.3');
            },
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg == 'ok')
                {
                    $('#signup_name_of_user').val('');
                    $('#signup_email_of_user').val('');

                    $('#mainmodal').modal();
                    $('#mainmodal').modal('show');
                  }



                else{
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                }
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Modal for successful completion-->
 <div id = "mainmodal" class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are not showing enough code. Why have a document.ready in the midddle of some other code? Also have a look at .hide and .show jQuery

Comment: It won't make a difference whether it is the following, I am just experimenting:

$("#mainmodal").removeClass('hidethis');
$('#mainmodal').popup();

Comment: Please click`<>` and provide a [mcve]

Comment: .popup() just initialises the popup. It does not pop it. For that the documentation tells me you need a specific class on the button that pops it. Your code example is not clear at all. We cannot guess what you are doing in your experimentation

Comment: I have only included the relevant bits because the code is long... i.e. everything works fine up until that point. The PHP code is fine because it is putting data into the DB and checking that the e-mail isn't already registered etc. There is an issue here with jquery...

Comment: Made updates to code above so that u can follow